# Agrupar informações com Vue

Tags: vue.js

Olá! Estou estudando vue e ao mesmo tempo tentando aplicar o que estou aprendendo em um projeto.

Surgiu uma dificuldade. Tenho uma lista de checkboxes com as marcas dos veículos, quando vou clicando vai carregando os modelos das marcas selecionadas, e desejo que ao carregar os modelos venha o nome da marca primeiro e abaixo os modelos.

Ex:

Chevrolet

- Onix
- Prima

FORD

- Gol
- Golf

```
<template>
  <div>  
    <div v-show="marcas.length">
      <h5>Marcas de interesse</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
        <div v-for="m in marcas">
          <input name="cliente_interessado[marca][]" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :value="m.id" v-on:click="clickMarca(m.id)" >
          <label class="form-check-label">{{ m.nome }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>

    <div v-if="loading">Carregando...</div>        

    <div v-show="modelos.length">
      <br>
      <h5 >Modelos de interesse</h5>
      <hr>
      <div class="form-group form-check">
        <div v-for="m in modelos">          
          <input name="cliente_interessado[modelo][]" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :value="m.id" >
          <label class="form-check-label">{{ m.marca }} - {{ m.nome }}</label>
        </div>
      </div>      
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>  
  import axios from 'axios';

  export default {      
    data() {          
      return {        
        marcas: [],
        modelos: [],        
        checkedNames: [],
        loading: false,
      }      
    },    
    created() {          
      axios.get('/api/marcas').then(response => (this.marcas = response.data.data))
    },
    methods: {
      clickMarca(value) {       
        if (this.checkedNames.find(item => item === value)) {
          var pos = this.checkedNames.indexOf(value);
          this.checkedNames.splice(pos, 1);
        } else {
          this.checkedNames.push(value)
        }

        this.loading = true

        axios.get('/api/modelos/' + "[" + this.checkedNames.toString() + "]")
          .then(response => (this.modelos = response.data.data))
          .finally(() => this.loading = false)        
      }     
    }
  }
</script>
```

[image: Como está hoje]

Comment: não pode criar os modelos dentro do objeto marcas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá você pode criar um array marcas_modelos, inicialmente com o marca_id e os modelos vazios.

```
...
    {
       "marca_id" : 1,
       "modelos" : []
    },
...
```

Ao clicar na marca você busca na sua api pelos modelos e aplica em modelos.
E faz um v-for nos modelos abaixo da marca.
Segue abaixo a sugestão de código e um link para o jsfiddle.

Note que simulei o retorno da sua api com arrays, pode ser que ela retorne valores diferentes, então você terá de adaptar o código conforme sua api.

[Exemplo funcionando no jsfiffle](https://jsfiddle.net/maslivak/4jf1tosv/133/)

[image: Imagem do resultado]

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div v-if="loading">Carregando...</div>
      <div v-show="marcas.length">
        <h5>Marcas de interesse</h5>
        <hr>
        <ul class="form-group form-check">
          <li v-for="m in marcas">
            <input :id="'marcaId' + m.id" name="cliente_interessado[marca][]" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :value="m.id" v-on:change="clickMarca(m.id, $event)">
            <label :for="'marcaId' + m.id" class="form-check-label">{{ m.nome }}</label>
            <div v-if="loading">Carregando...</div>
            <ul class="form-group form-check">
              <li v-for="md in marcasModelo(m.id)">
                <input :id="'modeloId' + md.id" name="cliente_interessado[modelo][]" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" :value="md.id">
                <label :for="'modeloId' + md.id" class="form-check-label">{{ md.nome }}</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </template>


<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      marcas: [],
      marcas_modelos: [],
      loading: false
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.loadMarcas();
  },
  methods: {
    loadMarcas() {
      //axios.get('/api/marcas').then(response => (this.marcas = response.data.data))
      //Simulando a chamada de marcas, aqui sua api devolverá as marcas e atribuirá a this.marcas...
      this.marcas = [
        {
          id: 1,
          nome: "CHEVROLET"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          nome: "FIAT"
        }
      ];
      let self = this;
      this.marcas.forEach(function(value) {
        self.marcas_modelos.push({
          marca_id: value.id,
          modelos: []
        });
      });
    },
    loadModelos(marca_id) {
      //this.loading = true
      //axios.get('/api/modelos/' + "[" + this.checkedNames.toString() + "]")
      //.then(response => (this.modelos = response.data.data))
      //.finally(() => this.loading = false)
      //Simulando a chamada de modelos, aqui sua api deverá devolver os modelos conforme a marca_id...
      let modelos = [
        {
          id: 1,
          marca_id: 1,
          nome: "PRISMA"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          marca_id: 1,
          nome: "ONIX"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          marca_id: 2,
          nome: "SIENA"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          marca_id: 2,
          nome: "PALIO"
        }
      ];
      // esse filter provavelmente não será necessário, sua api irá devolver somente o que você precisar.
      return modelos.filter(function(modelo) {
        return modelo.marca_id == marca_id;
      });
    },
    clickMarca(value, event) {
      let isCheched = event.target.checked;
      let modelos = [];
      if (isCheched) {
        modelos = this.loadModelos(value);
      }
      let marcaIndex = this.marcas_modelos.findIndex(x => x.marca_id == value);
      this.marcas_modelos[marcaIndex].modelos = modelos;
    },
    marcasModelo(marca_id) {
      let marcaIndex = this.marcas_modelos.findIndex(
        x => x.marca_id == marca_id
      );
      if (this.marcas_modelos[marcaIndex])
        return this.marcas_modelos[marcaIndex].modelos;
      return [];
    }
  }
};
</script>
```